# Category-slug not working

Tags: php, wordpress

I am developing a website for quotes, in that I want different category page template page for each category for that I followed below link of wordpress:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Category_Templates

According to that I made different category-popular `author.php` (also tried category-7.php bt wasn't worked) other than my original `category.php` file, but doesn't work. I also tried some other options like:

1) Tried this code in

```
functions.php
function wpse_category_single_template( $single_template ) {
    global $post;
    $all_cats = get_the_category();

    if ( $all_cats[0]->cat_ID == '1' ) {
        if ( file_exists(get_template_directory() . "/single-cat1.php") )           return get_template_directory() . "/single-cat1.php";
    } elseif ( $all_cats[0]->cat_ID == '2' ) {
        if ( file_exists(get_template_directory() . "/single-cat2.php") ) return get_template_directory() . "/single-cat2.php";
    }
    return $single_template;
}
add_filter( 'single_template', 'wpse_category_single_template' );
```

but wasn't worked

2) Changed my permalink structure.

3) Tried to put `if...else` condition in `category.php` file like this:

```
<?php if (is_category('ID')) : ?>
// Code For Category with defined ID
<?php else : ?>
// Code for else
<?php endif; ?>
```

But still no progress.

Actually wordpress doesn't find my `category-slug.php` file

What's wrong?

Comment: Perhaps it's a typo but you wrote "category-popular author.php" instead of "category-popular-author.php" (note the missing dash)

Answer (score 0):

Your file name should be `category-popular-author.php` not `category-popular author.php`. You have missing dash.

If your category ID is `7`, then I guess you have file in wrong directory. Because `category-7.php` should work.

From codex.

> The Template Hierarchy specifies that WordPress will use the first
>   Template file it finds in your current Theme's directory from the
>   following list:
>
> - category-slug.php
> - category-ID.php
> - category.php
> - archive.php
> - index.php

So `category-popular-author.php` should be in `wp-content/themes/CURRENT_THEME_NAME/category-popular-author.php`

Comment: yes may b category-popolar author.php should not work bcz of the missing dash.. but my category id is right it is 7 so category-7.php should work na!!! nd it is on the same path you mentioned in your answer.

Comment: Just tested it on my WP install. It works fine with slug and ID. Are you getting correct ID? Open category edit page and search for `tag_ID` in address bar. Though `category-popular-author.php` should work perfectly. What output do you get? Does it show default `category.php`?

Comment: yeahh...the category.php page is running imstead category-7.php

Comment: Lets chat [here](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74718/chat-with-user3580049)

Comment: hey I don't have enough reputation to start the conversation.. can we solve the problem here only?

Comment: Okay. If you edit your category.php, does the changes show up? And are category.php and category-7.php files in same folder?

Comment: Nope...Even I tried to put if..else condition in category.php like I menioned in my question's 3rd point but didn't work

Comment: Sounds like it gets `category.php` from another theme. Add something certain to start of that file. Like `print_r( 'It works!' );` and see if it prints it. Is your theme certainlly correct? Is the site live, so I can see it?

Comment: Right noe my category file is having if..else condition..like if is it category-7 then this template else some other template....but if I put this print_r( 'It works!' ); part in "if" part of my code it's not working while in else part which is original category.php this print_r( 'It works!' ); is working.